# Multi cell if statements true then add

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have a table that has multiple points of data that need to be added but only if certain criteria is/are met.

In scenario #1, property A needs to pull in both the "Base" and "Incremental" total spends (totals of January and February in ~column B).  In scenario #2, property B needs to pull in "Base" ONLY as there is no "Incremental."

My hope is to come with a formula that says I cell A3 = "Base" and A5 = Incremental, then sum B3+B5, but same formula should also allows for the second scenario (for property B) to return back JUST the "Base" spend in column B.

Help?

```
Cluster            Spend

Property  A        $881.72     
Base               $256.24     
January            $128.12     
February           $128.12    
Incremental        $625.47     
January            $128.12     
February           $497.35     

Property B         $149.87     
Base               $149.87    
January            $149.87
```

Comment: I don't understand... Where would "Incremental" be? In your example, scenario 1 has it in (given your cell naming) in A6 (after Feb), so what do you add?? Base + Incremental, Jan + Base + Incremental???? Please elaborate on your set-up....

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The formula needs to be contained in each property A,B, etc...cell.  This is the incorrect formula, but logically, i'm looking for something like this in each property's column B =IF(A3="Base",B3),IF(A3=BASE"&A6="INCREMENTAL",B3+B6).  Does that help make more sense? THANK YOU!

Comment: So, basically, always sum Base + (if it exists) incremental and ignore all other values? AND there is an empty between each property to know when the next property exists?? - Just trying to see what we have to work with here...

Comment: 95% Correct! Oh thank you for interpreting my question!  The only difference would be after each property, the next property begins, but my thought is that the cell would be far 99% likely to not be Base or Incremental.

Comment: What's the remaining 5%?? :)

Comment: HA! the 5% is that there is no space after each property. the NEXT property begins, but the formula should be fairly stable as the cells the formula is referencing are MORE likely going to be "january" or "february" or another property name...

Comment: Again, still not sure I completely understand, but I posted a solution that should show you how to only sum those 2 values wherever they may occur...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure I completely understand your question, based upon what I do understand - Assume your data was such that Property A's data was in range A2:B8, you could use a formula along the lines of:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,"Base",B2:B8) + SUMIF(A2:A8,"Incremental", B2:B8)
```

Please clarify where I might be mistaken if this doesn't give you what you're looking for.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Thank you so very much.  It did in fact work. I don't get how it ignores the "base" subtotal row and the "incremental" subtotal row.  I thought for sure it would double count, but it did work.  Greatly appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use the SUBTOTAL function:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ysnb.png

SUBTOTAL with function 109 sums the selected cells while ignoring hidden cells and cells containing SUBTOTALS with function 109.

Comment: Thanks! I think I explained it incorrectly.  I don't need the subtotal for ALL incremental and all base cells.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your explanation though?  I'm unable to open your worksheet.  I'm obviously a novice in this forum. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie myself. I've fixed the link. My solution may be a little more indirect than you'd like. Basically, you'll ignore the aggregate cells ("Base" and "Incremental") and only add the data at the most granular level. (Meaning you'll be adding Jan/Feb from Base then Jan/Feb from incremental). The pro of this approach is that if you need to change the dollar amount for any particular month, both the "Base" or "Incremental" rows will be updated as well as the total for "Property A"

Comment: That's genius!  Thank you! I do worry a bit about a vertical sequence where it says Base... month 1, month 2, next property Base... month 1, month 2 and it accidentally pulling the NEXT property's data, but at least it's closer.  THANK YOU AGAIN APPRECIATE YOUR BRAIN!